# What does here "lager plate" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is the sentence:

> For a more detailed  investigation of the porosity a small sample with ground surfaces was prepared out of the lager plate.

This is taken from a [technical text](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jcersj2/124/10/124_16107/_pdf) about development of polyvinylsilazane-derived ceramic matrix composites.

Comment: I guess it is a typo of either **larger** or **layer**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it is a simple typo, no useful answer can be written.